# Trying to bind variables that are changed in event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS page which contains the following buttons:

```
<button class="ui button" ng-click="startTimer()" ng-show="!timerRunning">START</button>
<button class="ui button" ng-click="stopTimer()" ng-show="timerRunning">STOP</button>
```

I also have this piece of code defined in my controller:

```
$scope.timerRunning = false;
$scope.timerDone = false;


$scope.startTimer = function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('timer-start');
    $scope.timerRunning = true;
    $scope.timerDone = false;
};

$scope.stopTimer = function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
    $scope.timerRunning = false;
    $scope.timerDone = true;
};


$scope.$on('timer-stopped', function (event, data) {
    console.log('Timer Stopped - data = ', data);
});

$scope.$on('timer-tick', function (event, args) {
    if (args.millis == 0) {
        $scope.stopTimer();
    }
});
```

I would expect that when timer hits 0 (it's a countdown timer [taken from here](http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer)) the flag `timerDone` and `timerRunning` would be changed and so would the buttons display. But in fact it doesn't happen. I debugged it and saw that I get into the `stopTimer()` method and that the variables are changed **but the buttons stay hidden/shown respectively as they were before the timer hit 0**.

I guess I'm missing something with the scope here as I'm pretty new to angular but I just couldn't figure out how to overcome this.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is all the relevant code.  Where is the timer in your markup?  What is models.competitors?  I highly recommend you create a plunkr or a jsFiddle for really fast help.

Comment: @PhilSandler I removed `model.competitors` because even when it's removed it doesn't work. Timer is defined as just `<timer>` and it sends even on every tick which works as expected. But the binding doesn't seem to work :/

I'm not sure about the `jsFiddle` - you meant I should put it as part of the question?

Comment: I mean: create a jsFiddle/plunkr that completely reproduces the problem.  It makes it so much easier for someone else to see the problem in action, debug it and provide help.  I have no idea if there are statistics on this, but I'd wager that posts that link to a repro case get answered many times faster than those that don't.

Comment: Actually, I think SO now has the built-in ability to do what jsFiddle does, so that might be the easiest way to post a repro.  :)

Comment: Could be the prototypal inheritance gotcha as described [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes). You should not bind to primitives.

Comment: You may be getting to 0 with no digest() cycle to update. There is a callback - 'finishCallback' that may be more appropriate  in the case, look at timer about line#242-ish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a prototypal inheritance issue like Rob J was right. What I did was to fix the even listener as follows (added `$scope.$apply()`):

```
$scope.$on('timer-tick', function (event, args) {
    if (args.millis == 0) {
        $scope.stopTimer();
        $scope.$apply();
    }
});
```